# Mondrian Filter on Date Dimension(s)

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I've built a simple OLAP cube with 2 date dimensions, a single low cardinality string dimension, and a single measure that just counts the rows in the fact table.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to filter on date dimensions. I have a query that works and produces the correct results, but it seems very inefficient. It looks like this:

```
SELECT
  [measures].[user_count] on 0,
  [gender].members on 1
FROM
  profiles
WHERE
  NonEmptyCrossJoin(
    { [birthday].[1960].[1].[1] : [birthday].[1989].[12].[31] },
    { [created_date].[2013].[1].[1] : [created_date].[2013].[12].[31] }
  )
```

Mondrian performs more than 400 SQL queries that look like this:

```
select
    "dates"."day" as "c0"
from
    "samtest"."dates" as "dates"
where
    ("dates"."month" = 8 and "dates"."year" = 1989)
group by
    "dates"."day"
order by
    CASE WHEN "dates"."day" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, "dates"."day" ASC
```

Then around 60 queries that look like this:

```
select
    "dates"."year" as "c0",
    "dates"."month" as "c1",
    "dates"."day" as "c2",
    "dates_1"."year" as "c3",
    "dates_1"."month" as "c4",
    "dates_1"."day" as "c5",
    "profiles"."gender" as "c6",
    count("profiles"."profile_id") as "m0"
from
    "samtest"."dates" as "dates",
    "samtest"."profiles" as "profiles",
    "samtest"."dates" as "dates_1"
where
    "profiles"."created_date" = "dates"."date"
and
    "dates"."year" = 2013
and
    "profiles"."birthday" = "dates_1"."date"
and
    "dates_1"."year" in (1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983)
and
    "profiles"."gender" = 'Unspecified'
group by
    "dates"."year",
    "dates"."month",
    "dates"."day",
    "dates_1"."year",
    "dates_1"."month",
    "dates_1"."day",
    "profiles"."gender"
```

The first time I run this it takes around 12 minutes to complete. Most of that time seems to be making the SQL queries, but even when I run it again after everything is cached, Mondrian still spends over 3 minutes computing the result. This seems strange to me because I can get the same result directly from the SQL database in less than a second.

Am I doing something completely wrong? Is this a bug? Is this just a not a good use case for OLAP?

I'm using Mondrian 3.6.1. The SQL database is Redshift. If anymore details about my configuration or schema would be useful, just let me know.